# Трансгрессия что оно значит?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, смысл

Трансгрессия, имеет ли это слово общий смысл, заложенный в него братьями Стругацкими в повести "Понедельник начинается в субботу" и Джоан Роулинг в серии книг про Гарри Поттера?

Comment: Как я понимаю, трансгрессия связана с перемещением в пространстве, но любопытно было бы узнать мнение других читателей, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Англичане пишут, что транс+грессия, это как про+грессия. Грессия они понимают как шагание или движение, транс - через, выход во вне, сквозь. Хотя, скорее всего кривое понимание или намеренное искажение слов вроде грядущий, грясти, грядка опять же. Просто есть латинское слово градус - условное обозначение неких делений. Так что трансгрессия само собой это не физический переход, а скорее на уровне восприятия или мышления. Вообще сам термин довольно известный в философии особенно постмодерна, связан с социальными границами. Да и граница скорее всего тот же корень - гра-/гря-.